# Problem with deleting the last element of a LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to implement `delete()` method in the `LinkedList`, which is a custom implementation of the Linked list data structure.

The following code seems to work properly if you delete the first element or an element in the middle. But if I'm trying to delete the last element in the `LinkedList`, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

How can I fix this problem?

*My code:*

```
public class LinkedList implements List {
    Node first;
    Node last;
    int size;
    
    public LinkedList() {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    
    public void add(double element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        
        if (first == null) {
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        } else {
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }
    
    // more methods (unrelated to the problem)
    
    public void delete(double element) {
        if (first == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (first.value == element) {
            first = first.next;
            return;
        }
        
        Node current = first;
        Node previous = null;
        
        while (current != null && current.next.value != element) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        
        if (current == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            current.next = current.next.next;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        if (first == null) {
            return "[]";
        } else {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("[");
            for (Node current = first; current != last; current = current.next) {
                sb.append(current.value);
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(last.value);
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

```
class LinkedListTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        
        list.add(5);
        list.add(25);
        list.add(-7);
        list.add(80);
        
        System.out.println(list);
        list.delete(80);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice simple case to learn about debugging. In a first step you could simply print the reference directly before the line where the exception occurs. Than go back even more to find the reason why there is an unexpected 'null' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the implementation of the `delete()` method:

- Condition of in the `while`-loop is not correct. Instead, checking if `current != null` you need to ensure that `current.next` is not `null` (*note that it's safe to access the `next` property of `current` because iteration starts with `current` being assigned to `first` which is proved to be non-null*).
- You're not considering the edge-case when the Node to remove is the last one. In such a case, when control breaks out from the `while`-loop `current.next` would point to `last` Node, and that would mean the `last` field should be reassigned (*since we're removing the last node*).

Also, local variable `previous` is redundant.

```
public void delete(double element) {
    if (first == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (first.value == element) {
        first = first.next;
        return;
    }
    
    Node current = first;
    
    while (current.next != null && current.next.value != element) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    
    if (current.next == last) { // reassign last if the Node to be removed is the current last Node
        last = current;
    }
    
    if (current.next != null) { // if the Node with given value was found
        current.next = current.next.next;
    }
}
```